# What's "busy waiting" in operating system?

Tags: operating-system

I'm researching about operating systems and I have a trouble with the **`busy waiting`** concept.

Is it true that "busy waiting" means an action must be waiting a condition to continue, but other waiting must wait some condition too, so what is the difference?

Comment: A two second Google search turns up this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). Please do some basic research yourself before posting here. Thanks.

Comment: I know Wiki can help with all of info, but thing I want in here is experience of programers about this concept. I know it's question not good but it not spam or anything illegal. So I realy unsatisfac for someone vote down it. Who want to answer when they see negative vote score.

Comment: Your question was voted down because it shows no effort, either in doing your own searching first or in writing the question here. You should do your own research (as I said in my last comment). StackOverflow is not a programming tutorial site, and it's not a replacement for doing your own searches and making an effort to find information yourself. The [help] has information about the types of questions that belong here. We answer specific questions about programming problems you're facing now, and "please explain an easy to find concept to me" is not a specific question.

Comment: Tks for give me your time!

Comment: I edited my question, I hope this specific than older.

Answer (score 12):

Busy waiting is where a process checks repeatedly for a condition- it is "waiting" for the condition, but it is "busy" checking for it. This will make the process eat CPU (usually).

[Wikipedia- Busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)

For example, I have a process that wants to know if there is an internet connection. Here is the psudeocode.

```
function stay_running_until_there_is_internet() {

    while(check_internet() == 0) {

        \\ wait

    }

}
```

Good luck!