# .NET Core Multithreading: Parent thread not executing after starting child thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

Trying to use .net core server as a WebSocket client to open multiple connections to a rocket.chat server,
I'm opening a new thread per connection since the socket server requires an answer to a ping request every couple of seconds.
The problem here is after calling the start method for the child thread the rest of the parent thread's code is not being executed and I could find neither the reason nor the solution.

Here's the `Websocket` class

```
public class WebSocket
{
    private Guid Id;
    private ClientWebSocket Client;
    private CancellationToken Token;
    private readonly ILogger<WebSocket> Logger;

    public WebSocket(Guid id, ILogger<WebSocket> logger)
    {
        Id = id;
        Logger = logger;
        Client = new ClientWebSocket();
        Token = new CancellationToken();
    }

    public Guid GetId()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
        await Connect();
        await Pong();
        return;
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("wss://<DNS>/websocket");
        await Client.ConnectAsync(uri, Token);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Client.State);
            if (Client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                Send("{\"msg\":\"connect\",\"version\":\"1\",\"support\":[\"1\"]}");
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            var res = await Recieve();
            if (res.Contains("connected"))
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Web socket successfully connected for user {User.Guid}", Id);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> Close()
    {
        await Client.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", Token);
        if (Client.State == WebSocketState.Closed)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async void Send(string data)
    {
        while (true) if (Client.State == WebSocketState.Open) break;
        var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
        await Client.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + data);
    }

    public async Task<string> Recieve()
    {
        ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        var res = await Client.ReceiveAsync(buffer, Token);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, res.Count);
    }

    public async Task Pong()
    {
        while (Client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            var res = await Recieve();
            if (res.Contains("ping"))
            {
                Send("{\"msg\": \"pong\"}");
                Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the object creation and starting it on a new thread

```
var socket = new WebSocket(guid, _socketLogger);
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(socket.Init));
Sockets.webSockets.Add(socket, thread);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
// what ever is here is not being executed
```

**UPDATE**

So I removed the thread usage and avoided the unawaitable asyncs, also removed the first while loop in connect cause it was pointed out to be useless.
The calling now starts with `await socket.Init()` but still I'm facing the same issue...

**Output** (after 30s)

```
Open
Web socket successfully connected for user <user guid>
{"msg": "ping"}"
Sent: {"msg": "pong"}
{"msg": "ping"}
Sent: {"msg": "pong"}
{"msg": "ping"}
Sent: {"msg": "pong"}
```

and this continues on while there's other stuff to write on the console after `init()`

Comment: That is a wonderfully horrible mix of multithreading, [unawaitable asyncs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687322/11683) and [busy waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904626/11683). I don't know where it deadlocks, but please pick one, not all three at once.

Comment: `Start` doesn't block, so the only way for the parent to stop executing is an exception. You don't need a thread to call `Init` anyway. Chance its signaturre to `async Task` and call `await socket.Init()`. Never use `async void` except for event handlers. In all other cases, an asynchronous method that returns no result should use the `async Task` signature

Comment: In `Connect`, the busy wait is pointless. `ConnectAsync` will return only when it succeeds. If it fails, it will throw an exception. ` async void Send(` is another bug, and the busy wait there isn't useful either

Comment: Can you post you log based on `` Console.WriteLine(Client.State);``?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your tips, so I made the changes but the issue is not resolved yet. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad that line was only being executed once cause the while loop would have broke as soon as the connection was open and in that only time, the result was also open

Comment: This line is rather suspect `while (true) if (Client.State == WebSocketState.Open) break;` I don't think it should be there. `async void Send` should be `async Task Send` and lower down `await Send();` also `Thread.Sleep(10000);` should be `await Task.Delay(10000);`